# Etymologies of noun and verb _wimple_

Tags: etymology, differences

Wiktionary and [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=wimple) show a different etymology for the noun *wimple*  (which has senses including “A cloth which usually covers the head...” and  “A ripple, as on the surface of water”) than Wiktionary shows for the verb *wimple* (which has senses including “To cover with a wimple” and “To cause ... to ripple or undulate [eg] *The wind wimples the surface of water*”).  From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wimple):

> Etymology 1 [noun]
>   From Middle English *wimpel*, from Old English *wimpel* (“veil, an article of women's dress; a covering for the neck, a cloak, a hood”), from Proto-Germanic *wimpilaz* (“wimple, scarf, veil”). ...
>
> Etymology 2 [verb]
>   From Middle English *wimplen* (“to cover, conceal; to fold, drape”)

Because Middle English *wimpel* and *wimplen* are so much alike, I assume they have a common ancestor, perhaps *wimpilaz*, perhaps something older.  What is that ancestor, if any?  Is there a better and more complete etymology for the verb *wimple*?

Comment: Both wiktionary and etymonline have the same etymology for the noun; > ME *wimpel* > OE *wimpel* > Proto-Germanic *wimpilaz. They differ in which cognates they mention, but that doesn't mean they contradict.

Answer (score 1):

You were just one click away. The Middle English verb comes from the Middle English noun: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wimplen#Middle_English

It's just a matter of Middle English having had an infinitive form that ends with *-an* or (as in this case) *-n* and that being what was used in the listing.